# How to retrieve the gameObject that is located at a specific index in a list?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a function that adds a gameObject to a list.

```
public void Foo(GameObject obj)
{
    List<GameObject> myList= new List<GameObject>
    {
        obj
    };
 }
```

My question is: How can I access the first gameObject that is inside of that list? I tried

```
 GameObject firstObj = myList.IndexOf(0);
```

But that doesn't work because I'm just creating a gameObject and initializing it to an int.

Comment: For semantic problems like this, you are best looking them up first before asking online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do

```
GameObject firstobj = myList[0];
```

like an array